# string return function not working - 'identifier is underfined'

Tags: c++

Relearning C/C++ after 3 years of JavaScript (I've gotten way too comfortable..)

I'm building a test file with input. 
The problem is within cTool, where the first function is not letting me return a string. I thought this was totally valid if the library is included in the header file? What am I overlooking here.

cTool.cpp

```
string getInfo(void) {
}

void parseInfo(void (*getInfo)()) {
}

float assessInfo(float number) {
}

...
```

cTool.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef ASSESS_GRADE_H
#define ASSESS_GRADE_H

#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string getInfo(void);
void parseInfo(void(*getInputFunc)());
float assessInfo(float number);
float assessInfo(char letter);
float assessInfo(int *array);

#endif
```

cMain.cpp

```
#include "cTool.h";

int main (void) {
    // function call from cTool.cpp
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `#include "cTool.h"` to `cTool.cpp`, not just to `cMain.cpp` only. Otherwise, when compiling `cTool.cpp`, the compiler doesn't know what a `string` is since it doesn't see your `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;` statements (BTW, `using namespace std;` in a header file is a very bad idea).

cTool.cpp

```
#include "cTool.h" // <-- ADD THIS!

std::string getInfo(void) {
}

void parseInfo(void (*getInfo)()) {
}

float assessInfo(float number) {
}

...
```

cTool.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef ASSESS_GRADE_H
#define ASSESS_GRADE_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string getInfo(void);
void parseInfo(void(*getInputFunc)());
float assessInfo(float number);
float assessInfo(char letter);
float assessInfo(int *array);

#endif
```

cMain.cpp

```
#include "cTool.h";

int main (void) {
    // function call from cTool.cpp
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is it a bad idea to use the namespace in header?

Comment: @RobertOchinski See [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/)